# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ diverge but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, trigonometry

Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{1}{n}}{n}$(I'm told it can be compared to the harmonic sequence, but I don't see the tangible comparison) diverge but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ converges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

$$\sin(1/n)\sim 1/n$$ 
as $n\to\infty$, so
$${\sin(1/n)\over n} \sim {1\over n^2}$$
as $n\to\infty$. This converges by the limit comparison test.

You have
$${\cos(1/n)\over n} \sim {1\over n}$$ as $n\to\infty$; this series will diverge by the limit comparison test.

Comment: Unnecessary since $1/n\downarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty$.