# For what $n$ is $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (it)}{i^n}$ bounded and why doesn't a sine behave the same way?

Tags: limits, parametric

I've been looking at a parametric curve $$\pmatrix{X \\ Y}=\pmatrix{\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\cos (it)}{i^n} \\ \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\sin (it)}{i^n}}$$ where, for the plots below, $N$ runs from $1 \rightarrow 300$ and $n=1,2$, respectively.

It seems that $X$ is unbounded/divergent in one, and bounded/convergent in the other, whereas $Y$ seems to be indifferent to $n$ and always be bounded. 
 
I use the term "bounded" to encapsulate that several different properties ($ \max (X),$ the area enclosed by $X,...$) could be a measure of this.

**My question:** For which $n \in \mathbb{R}$ is $X,Y$ bounded, and why does the sine always seem to be bounded?

I guess it could have something to do with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486632/why-does-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cos-frac1nn-diverge-but-sum-n-1) post, but I don't quite see how the argument in that post would be used for this problem, mostly because of my $t$, but perhaps it doesn't change anything?

As a sidenote, I tried introducing a $(-1)^{i+1}$ in the sums, but all this did was to mirror the graph around the left-most point of the original graph, so that $X$ diverged to $-\infty$ instead. Any ideas of why this is the case?

[image: n=1] $n=1$

[image: n=2] $n=2$

Oh, and here is a nice and wobbly version with $(-1)^{i}$:

[image] $n=1$

Any insights are much appreciated!

Comment: I suspect that sine function is symmetrical to zero and cosine is symmetrical to 1, thus sin cancels itself while cos adds itself in the series. (Sine symmetric to origin and Cosine symmetric to Y axis or pair and impair functions).

Comment: First, for $t=0$ do you understand why $\sum_i\frac{\cos 0}{i}$ diverges, but $\sum_i\frac{\sin 0}{i}$ converges?

Comment: @GEdgar Yeah, the first sum is the harmonic series, and the next is just $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function we should look at is called the [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) function
$$
\newcommand{\Li}{\operatorname{Li}}
\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\sign}{\operatorname{sign}}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k^n}=\Li_n(x)\tag{1}
$$
Then, your functions are
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kt)}{k^n}=\Re\left(\Li_n\left(e^{it}\right)\right)\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kt)}{k^n}=\Im\left(\Li_n\left(e^{it}\right)\right)\tag{3}
$$

---

For $n=1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ikt}}k
&=-\log\left(1-e^{it}\right)\\
&=-\log(2-2\cos(t))+i\sign(t)\left(\frac\pi2-\frac{|t|}2\right)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
The real part of $(4)$ says
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kt)}k=\infty\tag{5}
$$
and the imaginary part of $(4)$ says
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kt)}k\right|=\frac\pi2\tag{6}
$$

---

For $n=2$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6\tag{7}
$$
Therefore, by [Dominated Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) (which is valid for infinite sums using a discrete measure),
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ikt}}{k^2}
&=\frac{\pi^2}6\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
The real part of $(8)$ is
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kt)}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6\tag{9}
$$
and the imaginary part of $(8)$ is
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kt)}{k^2}=0\tag{10}
$$

---

The case for any real $n\gt1$ is similar to $n=2$ since for $n\gt1$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^n}=\zeta(n)\lt\infty\tag{11}
$$

Comment: In the line just before "Thus", how do you separate out the real and the imaginary parts? I'm guessing that this is what allows you to take the limit of the $\cos$ and the $\sin$ separately? In general, I'm having a hard time understanding the steps involved in the "Thus", so if you could elaborate, I'd be grateful!

Also, I'm afraid that this doesn't answer my question entirely, since this is only for $n=1$. Is it easy to generalize? Will the $\cos$ sum ever converge, and if so, when?

Comment: Do you know how to take the [logarithm of a complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)? $\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\arg(z)$

Comment: I do now! One last thing before I accept this beautiful answer (I only allow myself this since it was part of the original question): Where in between $1$ and $2$ does the convergence set in? I.e. which is the smallest $n$ I can choose and have both sums converge?

Comment: @Lovsovs: I have extended $(11)$ for real $n$.

Comment: Ah, sorry I had read that incorrectly, thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: @Lovsovs: No apologies needed. I just extended $(11)$ from only considering integer $n$ to considering real $n$.

Comment: Good good, then I haven't yet gone completely insane!

Answer (score 1):

*This is too long for a comment*, and  a slightly different view-point than the excellent answer by robjohn, for the ones not knowing non-elementary functions:

For $n>1$, the series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(kt)}{k^n}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(kt)}{k^n}$ are uniformly convergent (by [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) since the series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}1/k^n$ converges for $n>1$.

Since we have continuous functions converging uniformly we know that the limits are continuous functions, and we should not be surprised of the boundedness.

The case $0<n\leq 1$ is more interesting. In this case we can use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) for convergence.

Due to periodicity, it is sufficient to consider $0\leq t<2\pi$. From the well-known formulas (these can be proven using geometric sums)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N\cos(kt)=\cos\bigl((N+1)t/2\bigr)\frac{\sin(Nt/2)}{\sin(t/2)}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N\sin(kt)=\sin\bigl((N +1)t/2\bigr)\frac{\sin(Nt/2)}{\sin(t/2)}
$$
we find that, at least for fixed $t$ in $0<t<2\pi$,
$$
\Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^N\cos(kt)\Bigr|\leq\frac{1}{\sin(t/2)}
$$
and
$$
\Bigl|\sum_{k=1}^N\sin(kt)\Bigr|\leq\frac{1}{\sin(t/2)}
$$
*uniformly* in $N$. Moreover, the sequence $k\mapsto 1/k^n$ is clearly decreasing in $k$ and has limit $0$ as $k\to+\infty$. Dirichlet's test applies, and we find that the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(kt)}{k^n}\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(kt)}{k^n}
$$
converge for $0<n\leq 1$ and $0<t<2\pi$ and, thus, *for each $t$*, the partial sums are bounded.

The case $t=0$ remains. But for $t=0$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{\cos(kt)}{k^n}=\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k^n}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{\sin(kt)}{k^n}=\sum_{k=1}^N 0=0.
$$

The first sum tends to $+\infty$ as $N\to+\infty$ and the second sum clearly converges to $0$ s $N\to+\infty$.