# Showing that $\sum _{n=1}^\infty {\dfrac{\cos {\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}}}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show that $$\sum _{n=1}^\infty {\dfrac{\cos {\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}}}$$ is divergent. Context: I'm trying to show that the series $e^{i \pi /n}/\sqrt{n}$ is divergent. We can see that $\dfrac {\sin {\pi/n}}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \dfrac {\pi}{n \sqrt{n}}$ and the latter is a convergent p-series. Now returning to my original question, obviously that series is not absolute convergent. But I couldn't find a way to test its convergence. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

P.S. comments about the complex series are also welcome (for example, for some different approach I could use, but I won't add the tag for complex analysis because the original question is more specific).

Comment: **Hint :** Notice that $\frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sqrt n}$ is positive for all $n$ big enough. So it's convergent iff it's absolutely convergent... Now, $\frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sqrt n}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$... I let you conclude.

Comment: $\cos(\pi/n) \ge 1/2$ for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: cosine is bounded and then $(1/n)^.5$  is greater than $1/n$ for all $n$, so now you can use the harmonic series

Comment: A similar question: [Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ diverge but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{n}$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486632/why-does-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cos-frac1nn-diverge-but-sum-n-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}),\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>0$ for all $n\geq 3$, so we can use the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})=1
$$
Thus,  we will conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ converges. Because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ diverge, the desired sum also diverge.